# Removing regular expression from string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following string:

`/home/user/Documents/something/`

I'd like to remove the `*/` part at the end of it. In this case this is `something/`. How can I achive that with java?

Comment: Try this  I have tested in regularexpressplanet.com /+[a-z]+/$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex to do this, below is a non-regex solution using String manipulation methods:

```
    String s = "/home/user/Documents/something/";
    String sub =s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("/"));
    System.out.println(sub.substring(0,sub.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
```

Comment: It's almost fine, but it removes "\something\" instead of "something\" like it should.

Comment: @soulreaver now it would :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
str =    str.replaceAll("[^/]*/$","");
```

didn't test, should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. It will remove the last past from your String :

```
        String str = "/home/user/Documents/something/";

    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(/.+?/)(\\w+?/$)");
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(str);

    while (matcher1.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher1.group(1));
    }
```